# Jquery: Change input submit value after the element has loaded

Tags: jquery, submit-button

I am trying to change the value of this input from "Search" to "Filter":

```
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="refinementSearchButton" class="IDX-refineSubmit" id="IDX-resultsRefineSubmit">
```

I have no control over the input itself, which is inserted via javascript. I do have control of the wrapper, so I can add javascript to the page.

I need to wait until everything has rendered, or at least the input itself, and then change the input value.

I thought this would work to look for the ID of the input and then change it once it is detected:

```
$(window).load(function ()
{
    var i = setInterval(function ()
    {
        if ($('#IDX-resultsRefineSubmit').length)
        {
            clearInterval(i);

            // execute code here

    $("#IDX-resultsRefineSubmit").prop('value', 'Filter');

        }
    }, 100);
});
```

However this does not work.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Add, `alert('test');` after the clear interval. That way we'll know if it's ever firing or not.

Comment: Is the value of #refinementSearchButton set via javascript?  If it is already set in the HTML, then you do not need to use window load, just make sure the JS runs after the HTML

Comment: Also, you can use $("#IDX-resultsRefineSubmit").val('Filter'); to set the value

Comment: Hmm... alert('test'); does not fire...

Comment: The value of #refinementSearchButton is part of block of content that is being included via Javascript.

Comment: Just out of curiosity I added this as a separate script:

`$(document).ready( function () {
  
  alert("Hello, world")
  
}); `

It also does not fire, so something else is strange with the way the page is loading.

Comment: I can't publish the page that I am working on but here is another site that is using the exact same IDX service: [link](http://realestate.crescentcityliving.com/idx/results/homes?lp=240000&hp=520000&bd=1&tb=1&widgetReferer=true&city[]=32614). You can see next to the Sort By (least expensive)  box above the map the "Search" button. This is the button I need to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a javascript conflict with the version that was loading the page contents. It turns out that the $ variable was already in use, here's what worked:

```
 var jQuery = jQuery.noConflict();

    jQuery(function(){

    jQuery("#IDX-resultsRefineSubmit").val('Filter');  

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `$(window).load` to `$(document).ready`

https://jsfiddle.net/847gn6w5/

Comment: It's working in my fiddle. So you must have other code somewhere breaking things.

Comment: Yes, it was a javascript conflict that was stopping it.